# Auto start session on first use

Tags: php, session

I want a solution that i when first use the variable `$_SESSION` in every my php files, the function `session_start()` be called automatically. otherwise not.

I can call it in `auto-prepend-file` or use `session.auto_start`, but i will prevent any overhead process when i dont use session in a file.

Comment: Create a wrapper class around `$_SESSION`. Instead of using `$_SESSION` directly, you'd use something like `$mySessionWrapper->set('foo', 'bar')`. Then you can implement any session starting logic you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

But you could wrap your session functionality inside a class and handle the starting of the session inside the session class.

```
class Session {

    public function __construct() {
        session_start();
    }

    public function set($k, $v) {
        $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
    }

    ...

}
```

The usage would then be:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->set('key', 'value');
```

Otherwise there's another ugly solution which will spare you the `session_start()` or `$session = new Session();` line: to create a static class such as:

```
class Session {

    private static $inited = false;

    public static function check() {
        if (!$inited) {
            session_start();
            $inited = true;
        }
    }

    public static function set($k, $v) {
        self::check();
        $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
    }

    ...

}
```

then you would just create all your methods calling the `self::check()` at the beginning which will start the session if not already initialized. And the usage would be simply:

```
Session::set('key', 'value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Session class and instantiate it using a Singleton Pattern:

```
class Session {
  private function __construct() {
    session_start();
  }

  private static $instance = false;
  public static function getInstance() {
    if(self::$instance == false) {
      self::$instance == new Session();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not even the singleton pattern: I can instantiate your class as: `$s = new Session();`

Comment: WHy not? Its function is to ensure one instantiation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: The constructor is public -.-

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a session automatically, you will have to find the below line in your php.ini file and change the value from 0 to 1 and restart the your server.

session.auto_start = 1

or in htaccess

php_value session.auto_start 1

Which is auto start for all but that does not mean it create overhead